# How do I set up multisite on Digitalocean?

Tags: multisite

I am trying to setup multisite with the Digital ocean as host. I am using Namecheap as the DNS. Is there an easy way for this all to be set up or is it very complex?

Comment: Might want to read Digitalocean's docs and guides.

Comment: It's a placce to start

Comment: Yes and if you are just starting out on unmanaged VPS then it's going to be a very long road of learning.

Comment: Complete newb status, so yes I was already assuming that there would be a lot of learning (16 hours to just set up the site originaly) and this is for my own site to have multiple uses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's easy.
You should start reading  Digitalocean's documentation, for newb it will take few while to understand the whole scenario but you if have past experienced with managing VPS server then i believe it will be fun for you.
This documentation may help you : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-using-multisite